# Writing to a set of objects as a single dictionary in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have created a set of models to allow users to define custom fields for certain objects within a Django project. This allows users to store data which is pertinent to their specific use case without modifying the database schema. For example, the project includes a built-in `Site` model which has a name, address, etc. A user could create a custom field for this model if they also wanted to store, for example, the named point of contact for each site.

First, the user creates a custom field and assigns it to the model(s) they want to have that field. This is represented by a `CustomField` object. (A simplified version of the model is provided here. The full source is [available here](https://github.com/digitalocean/netbox/blob/v2-develop/netbox/extras/models.py) for anyone interested.)

```
class CustomField(models.Model):
    obj_type = models.ManyToManyField(ContentType, related_name='custom_fields', verbose_name='Object(s)')
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=CUSTOMFIELD_TYPE_CHOICES, default=CF_TYPE_TEXT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

A second model holds the custom field data for each object:

```
class CustomFieldValue(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey('CustomField', related_name='values')
    obj_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    obj_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    obj = GenericForeignKey('obj_type', 'obj_id')
    serialized_value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So in our example, we would create a CustomField named `point_of_contact` for the Site model, and a `CustomFieldValue` instance for each Site which has a POC.

I have created a serializer to represent custom fields in the API as a single child object. For example, a Site might appear as:

```
{
    "id": 42,
    "name": "My Site",
    "slug": "site-1",
    "physical_address": "123 Fake St",
    ...
    "custom_fields": {
        "point_of_contact": "Homer Simpson",
        "decommissioned": false
    }
}
```

A simplified version of the serializer is below ([full version](https://github.com/digitalocean/netbox/blob/v2-develop/netbox/extras/api/customfields.py#L18)):

```
class CustomFieldSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    Extends a ModelSerializer to render any CustomFields and their values associated with an object.
    """
    custom_fields = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_custom_fields(self, obj):

        # Gather all CustomFields applicable to this object
        fields = {cf.name: None for cf in self.context['view'].custom_fields}

        # Attach any defined CustomFieldValues to their respective CustomFields
        for cfv in obj.custom_field_values.all():
            fields[cfv.field.name] = cfv.value

        return fields
```

The `custom_fields` context is provided by a custom APIView ([full version](https://github.com/digitalocean/netbox/blob/v2-develop/netbox/extras/api/views.py#L14)):

```
class CustomFieldModelAPIView(object):
    """
    Include the applicable set of CustomField in the view context.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomFieldModelAPIView, self).__init__()
        self.content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.queryset.model)
        self.custom_fields = self.content_type.custom_fields.all()
```

This works great for read operations, but I'm stuck on how to support the creation and modification of custom fields via the API. The crux of the issue seems to be that a serializer expects to work on a set of fields comprising a single object, rather than a set of objects.

How can I extend this serializer to support write access to multiple CustomFieldValues as a single object? Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: does my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    custom_fields = serializer.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    custom_fields_write = serializer.DictField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        custom_fields_data = validated_data.pop('custom_fields_write')
        site = super(MySerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        for key, val in custom_fields_data.items():
            cf = CustomField.objects.get(name=key)
            CustomFieldValue.objects.create(field=cf, obj=site, serialized_value=val)
        return site
```

you can use a similar update method.

Comment: I also needed to add a `to_internal_value()` method to CustomFieldsSerializer, but this was the heart of it. Thanks!

Comment: @JeremyStretch why did you need a to internal value? Was it for converting the dict of custom fields to valid python values?

Comment: Just for validation. I needed to ensure that the custom fields specified exist, etc.

Comment: I think for validation use validate_<field_name> method or for object level validation use validate method.